# Calling method in java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a method,

```
private String createSubjectColumnForOutgoing(Message message)
{
    //TODO : Changes for blocking messages of spam users


    if(message.getReceiverEnvelope() != null && message.getReceiverEnvelope().getUser() != null && message.getReceiverEnvelope().getUser().isBlocked())
    {
        return I18N.IN_REVIEW_BY_TEAM.msg();
    }


    return StringUtils.deSanitizeSpecialCharacters(message.getSubject());
}
```

and this method is called like this,

```
case OUTGOING:
            table.addGeneratedColumn(I18N.MESSAGETABLE_HEADER_SUBJECT.msg(), this::createSubjectColumnForOutgoing);
            break;
```

And the constructor in the class are,

```
public MessageTable(Directory directory, boolean withFilter, Device device)
{
    this(directory, new FilterConfiguration(withFilter), device);
}

public MessageTable(Directory directory, FilterConfiguration filterConfiguration, Device device)
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(directory);
    Objects.requireNonNull(device);

    this.directory = directory;

    dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.SHORT).withLocale(LocaleAware.super.getLocale());

    tableFooter = createTableFooter();

    openButton = createOpenButton();
    newButton = createNewButton();
    messageTable = createTable(device);

    tableFooter.addComponent(newButton, 0);
    tableFooter.addComponent(openButton, 1);

    final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    layout.addComponent(createFilterComponent(filterConfiguration));
    layout.addComponents(tableFooter, messageTable);
    layout.setComponentAlignment(tableFooter, Alignment.MIDDLE_LEFT);

    rootLayout = layout;
    setCompositionRoot(rootLayout);

}
```

When calling this method `createSubjectColumnForOutgoing` there is no parameter passed, and it is working perfectly. I am not able to understand from where data is coming in Message object. I googled but not able to understand it. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Code of addGeneratedColumn

```
public void addGeneratedColumn(Object id, Function<BEANTYPE, ?> generatedColumn)
{
    String header = null;
    if(id instanceof String)
    {
        header = (String) id;
    }
    addGeneratedColumn(header, id, (source, itemId, columnId) -> generatedColumn.apply(itemId));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this::createSubjectColumnForOutgoing` is a method reference, not an execution of the `createSubjectColumnForOutgoing` method.

The `table.addGeneratedColumn()` method, to which you pass the method reference, may be calling the method of the functional interface implemented by this method reference. If it does, it passes a `Message` instance to it.

You haven't included the code of `addGeneratedColumn()`, so I don't know what type of functional interface it expects (perhaps a `Function`).

EDIT:

Following your edit, `Function<BEANTYPE, ?> generatedColumn` is the functional interface implemented by the method reference you pass to `addGeneratedColumn()`. This means that `generatedColumn.apply(itemId)` is the statement that executes the `createSubjectColumnForOutgoing()` method, and you can see that `itemId` is passed to the method. This means that `itemId` must be a `Message` instance.

Note that `addGeneratedColumn(Object id, Function<BEANTYPE, ?> generatedColumn)` doesn't execute the `createSubjectColumnForOutgoing()` method either. It passes a functional interface (implemented by a lambda expression) that can execute that method to a second `addGeneratedColumn` method.

Comment: I have updated the question with code of addGeneratedColumn()

Comment: Thanks for the help @Eran.